# Pattern Matching for URL classification

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching

As a part of a project, me and a few others are currently working on a URL classifier. What we are trying to implement is actually quite simple : we simply look at the URL and find relevant keywords occuring within it and classify the page accordingly.

Eg : If the url is : http://cnnworld/sports/abcd, we would classify it under the category "sports"

To accomplish this, we have a database with mappings of the format : Keyword -> Category

Now what we are currently doing is, for each URL, we keep reading all the data items within the database, and using String.find() method to see if the keyword occurs within the URL. Once this is found, we stop.

But this approach has a few problems, the main ones being :

(i) Our database is very big and such repeated querying runs extremely slowly

(ii) A page may belong to more than one category and our approach does not handle such cases. Of-course, one simple way to ensure this would be to continue querying the database even once a category match is found, but this would only make things even slower.

I was thinking of alternatives and was wondering if the reverse could be done - Parse the url, find words occuring within it and then query the database for those words only.

A naive algorithm for this would run in O( n^2 ) - query the database for all substrings that occur within the url.

I was wondering if there was any better approach to accomplish this. Any ideas ?? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

In our commercial classifier we have a database of 4m keywords :) and we also search the body of the HTML, there are number of ways to solve this:

1. Use Aho-Corasick, we have used a modified algorithm specially to work with web content, for example treat: tab, space, \r, \n as space, as only one, so two spaces would be considered as one space, and also ignore lower/upper case.
2. Another option is to put all your keywords inside a tree (std::map for example) so the search becomes very fast, the downside is that this takes memory, and a lot, but if it's on a server, you wouldn't feel it.

Comment: Please do not paste signature or adds in any post or question. You can do it on your profile if you'd like, but it creates noise on SO thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think your suggestion of breaking apart the URL to find useful bits and then querying for just those items sounds like a decent way to go.

I tossed together some Java that might help illustrate code-wise what I think this would entail. The most valuable portions are probably the regexes, but I hope the general algorithm of it helps some as well:

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.List;

public class CategoryParser 
{
    /** The db field that keywords should be checked against */
    private static final String DB_KEYWORD_FIELD_NAME = "keyword";

    /** The db field that categories should be pulled from */
    private static final String DB_CATEGORY_FIELD_NAME = "category";

    /** The name of the table to query */
    private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "KeywordCategoryMap";

    /**
     * This method takes a URL and from that text alone determines what categories that URL belongs in.
     * @param url - String URL to categorize
     * @return categories - A List&lt;String&rt; of categories the URL seemingly belongs in
     */
    public static List<String> getCategoriesFromUrl(String url) {

        // Clean the URL to remove useless bits and encoding artifacts
        String normalizedUrl = normalizeURL(url);

        // Break the url apart and get the good stuff
        String[] keywords = tokenizeURL(normalizedUrl);

        // Construct the query we can query the database with
        String query = constructKeywordCategoryQuery(keywords);

        System.out.println("Generated Query: " + query);

        // At this point, you'd need to fire this query off to your database,
        // and the results you'd get back should each be a valid category
        // for your URL. This code is not provided because it's very implementation specific,
        // and you already know how to deal with databases.


        // Returning null to make this compile, even though you'd obviously want to return the
        // actual List of Strings
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the protocol, if it exists, from the front and
     * removes any random encoding characters
     * Extend this to do other url cleaning/pre-processing
     * @param url - The String URL to normalize
     * @return normalizedUrl - The String URL that has no junk or surprises
     */
    private static String normalizeURL(String url)
    {
        // Decode URL to remove any %20 type stuff
        String normalizedUrl = url;
        try {
            // I've used a URLDecoder that's part of Java here,
            // but this functionality exists in most modern languages
            // and is universally called url decoding
            normalizedUrl = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee)
        {
            System.err.println("Unable to Decode URL. Decoding skipped.");
            uee.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Remove the protocol, http:// ftp:// or similar from the front
        if (normalizedUrl.contains("://"))
        {
            normalizedUrl = normalizedUrl.split(":\\/\\/")[1];
        }

        // Room here to do more pre-processing

        return normalizedUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Takes apart the url into the pieces that make at least some sense
     * This doesn't guarantee that each token is a potentially valid keyword, however
     * because that would require actually iterating over them again, which might be
     * seen as a waste.
     * @param url - Url to be tokenized
     * @return tokens - A String array of all the tokens
     */
    private static String[] tokenizeURL(String url)
    {
        // I assume that we're going to use the whole URL to find tokens in
        // If you want to just look in the GET parameters, or you want to ignore the domain
        // or you want to use the domain as a token itself, that would have to be
        // processed above the next line, and only the remaining parts split
        String[] tokens = url.split("\\b|_");

        // One could alternatively use a more complex regex to remove more invalid matches
        // but this is subject to your (?:in)?ability to actually write the regex you want

        // These next two get rid of tokens that are too short, also.

        // Destroys anything that's not alphanumeric and things that are
        // alphanumeric but only 1 character long
        //String[] tokens = url.split("(?:[\\W_]+\\w)*[\\W_]+");

        // Destroys anything that's not alphanumeric and things that are
        // alphanumeric but only 1 or 2 characters long
        //String[] tokens = url.split("(?:[\\W_]+\\w{1,2})*[\\W_]+");

        return tokens;
    }

    private static String constructKeywordCategoryQuery(String[] keywords)
    {
        // This will hold our WHERE body, keyword OR keyword2 OR keyword3
        StringBuilder whereItems = new StringBuilder();

        // Potential query, if we find anything valid
        String query = null;

        // Iterate over every found token
        for (String keyword : keywords)
        {
            // Reject invalid keywords
            if (isKeywordValid(keyword))
            {
                // If we need an OR
                if (whereItems.length() > 0)
                {
                    whereItems.append(" OR ");
                }

                // Simply append this item to the query
                // Yields something like "keyword='thisKeyword'"
                whereItems.append(DB_KEYWORD_FIELD_NAME);
                whereItems.append("='");
                whereItems.append(keyword);
                whereItems.append("'");
            }
        }

        // If a valid keyword actually made it into the query
        if (whereItems.length() > 0)
        {
            query = "SELECT DISTINCT(" + DB_CATEGORY_FIELD_NAME + ") FROM " + DB_TABLE_NAME
                    + " WHERE " + whereItems.toString() + ";";
        }

        return query;
    }

    private static boolean isKeywordValid(String keyword)
    {
        // Keywords better be at least 2 characters long
        return keyword.length() > 1
                // And they better be only composed of letters and numbers
                && keyword.matches("\\w+")
                // And they better not be *just* numbers
                // && !keyword.matches("\\d+") // If you want this
                ;
    }

    // How this would be used
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> soQuestionUrlClassifications = getCategoriesFromUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046178/pattern-matching-for-url-classification");
        List<String> googleQueryURLClassifications = getCategoriesFromUrl("https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=spring+is+a+new+service+instance+created#hl=en&sugexp=ciatsh&gs_nf=1&gs_mss=spring%20is%20a%20new%20bean%20instance%20created&tok=lnAt2g0iy8CWkY65Te75sg&pq=spring%20is%20a%20new%20bean%20instance%20created&cp=6&gs_id=1l&xhr=t&q=urlencode&pf=p&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&oq=url+en&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2176d1af1be1f17d&biw=1680&bih=965");
    }
}
```

The Generated Query for the SO link would look like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM KeywordCategoryMap WHERE keyword='stackoverflow' OR keyword='com' OR keyword='questions' OR keyword='10046178' OR keyword='pattern' OR keyword='matching' OR keyword='for' OR keyword='url' OR keyword='classification'
```

Plenty of room for optimization, but I imagine it to be much faster than checking the string for every possible keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Aho-corasick algorithm is best for searching intermediate string with one traversal. You can form a tree (aho-corasick tree) of your keyword. At the last node contains a number mapped with a particular keyword.

Now, You just need to traverse the URL string on the tree. When you got some number (work as flag in our scenario), it means that we got some mapped category. Go on with that number on hash map and find respective category for further use.

I think this will help you.
Go to this link: [good animation of aho-corasick by ivan](http://blog.ivank.net/aho-corasick-algorithm-in-as3.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have (many) fewer categories than keywords, you could create a regex for each category, where it would match any of the keywords for that category.  Then you'd run your URL against each category's regex.  This would also address the issue of matching multiple categories.